# Remove indent from label

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uilabel

I have a label where the first word starts with an indent. I dont want the paragraph to start with an indent.

I need something like this:

```
LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum
LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum
LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum
LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum.
```

Where as I am getting :

```
   LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum
LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumm
LoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsumLoremIpsum.
```

I am using the following code:

```
UILabel *b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,108,124,90)];

NSString *strr =[aPostIntro objectAtIndex:indexPath.section*2];
if(strr.length > 270)
{
    strr =  [[strr substringToIndex:270] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

NSAttributedString *string1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strr 
                                                              attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                              paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ,
                                                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, 
                                                                                         nil]];
b1Lab1.attributedText = string1;

// NSString *stri = [aPostIntro objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 9;
b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8];
b1Lab1.tag=111;
b1Lab1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: check what you're getting in `NSString *strr =[aPostIntro objectAtIndex:indexPath.section*2];` -- the string itself must be having spaces in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

```
NSString *strr =[aPostIntro objectAtIndex:indexPath.section*2];
NSLog(@"%@",strr); //check strr
```

and confirm that `strr` itself doesn't contain any starting spaces.

---

If you replace `strr` to:

> strr = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
>   diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
>   erat volutpat..."

The output is as per your expectation.

Comment: Yup.The String contains the space! Now how do I format it for only the first word?

Comment: @koherent : `strr = [myText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];` -- **NOTE**: this will remove **all** **leading** and **trailing** whitespaces from the string. Also, it will convert *all** double-space / triple-space / multiple-spaces (_between words_) to single spaces.

Answer (score 0):

use this code may it help you.....

UILabel *b1Lab1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,108,124,90)];

```
            NSString *strr =[aPostIntro objectAtIndex:indexPath.section*2];
            if(strr.length > 270)
            {
                strr =  [[strr substringToIndex:270] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
            }

            NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0;
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

            NSAttributedString *string1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strr
                                                                         attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                     paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ,
                                                                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, 
                                                                                     nil]];
            string1.Trim();
            b1Lab1.attributedText = string1;

            // NSString *stri = [aPostIntro objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

            b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            b1Lab1.numberOfLines = 9;
            b1Lab1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8];
            b1Lab1.tag=111;
            b1Lab1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line out:

```
b1Lab1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```